# Automator - a screenshot of a some part of a website. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screenshot, automator

I wonder if there is a chance to program automator to go on a store website category and then select all the products on that website to open each item on the new tab? Or maybe any software which can get all the product URL from the particular website?

As you can see on this website there are 14 products:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmcYw.gif)

The next step would be to take a screenshot of that product/ A fragment of the website - (I guess based on HTML)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR0Jp.gif)

I’ve tried to automate it with an auto clicker but it’s so hard to make the perfect macros for each website as Height and width are every time different… So I just failed. For 3 weeks Each day, I take about 200 screenshots like this in example… so it gets extremely boring and I’m simply fed up…

I appreciate every tip, hint how I could make it work… maybe a software or a script? I’ve been scrolling thru the web but so far nothing except those tools for web testing… unfortunately I’m not advanced in coding… a total noob so any help will be welcomed :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Puppeteer (javascript).

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandlescreenshotoptions

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible using selenium in python.

Setup and installation of Selenium

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc

Selenium screenshots github repository

> https://github.com/PyWizards/Selenium_Screenshot